# Showing continuity - epsilon-delta situation

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]\times [c,d]\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $h(x,y):= \int_a^x f(z,y)dz$. Then, $h$ is continuous on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$.

For $(x,y),(x',y')\in [a,b]\times [c,d]$ we have

$$
|h(x,y)-h(x',y')| 
= |\int_a^{x'}f(z,y)dz + \int_{x'}^{x}f(z,y)dz - \int_a^{x'}f(z,y')dz| \\
\leq \int_a^{x'}|f(z,y)-f(z,y')|dz + |\int_{x'}^x f(z,y)dz|$$

Now, $f$ is bounded and equicontinuous on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$. It is intuitively clear to me that the integrals on the right side get arbitrarily small, if just $(x,y)$ and $(x\prime,y\prime)$ get close enough. However, I fail to express this in terms of epsilon-delta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded there exists $M > 0$ such that $|f(x,y)| \leqslant M$ for all $(x,y) \in [a,b]\times [c,d]$.  Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta(\epsilon) > 0$ such that $|f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2,y_2)| < \epsilon$ when $\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2} < \delta(\epsilon)$.

Suppose $\sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y - y')^2} < \min \left[\frac{\epsilon}{2M},\delta\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}\right)\right]$.

It follows that $|x-x'| \leqslant \sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y - y')^2} < \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$.

We also have   $\sqrt{(z-z)^2 + (y - y')^2} = |y-y'| < \delta\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}\right)$, and by uniform continuity that $|f(z,y) - f(z,y')| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$ for all $z \in [a,x']$.

Thus,

$$|h(x,y)-h(x',y')| \leqslant \int_a^{x'}|f(z,y)-f(z,y')|\,dz + \int_{x'}^x |f(z,y)|\,dz\\ < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}|x'-a|+M|x-x'|< \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}(b-a)+M\frac{\epsilon}{2M}= \epsilon$$.

Comment: Ah, very nice. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Miriam: You're welcome.